# Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':myApp:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio

Not exactly sure how this happened.

Running latest Android Studio version (0.3.6). Have the right Gradle version in properties sheet (1.8).

One thing I'm noticing but I don't understand right now is in the project panel on the left, the src, main, java, com.my.package and the files in the package are underlined with the red squiggly line like there is an error with them.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

As requested, here's the full output from gralew build --stacktrace

```
:Lelantos:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                 
:Lelantos:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:prepareDebugDependencies             
:Lelantos:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE  
:Lelantos:processDebugResources FAILED      

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Lelantos:processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Lelantos:processDebugResources'

* Try:    
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Lelantos:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Lelantos:processDebugResources'
        at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platf
orms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\Jeff\AndroidStudioProjects\LelantosProject\Lelantos\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Jeff\AndroidStudioProjects\LelantosP
roject\Lelantos\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\Jeff\AndroidStudioProjects\LelantosProject\Lelantos\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Jeff\AndroidStudioProjects\LelantosProject\Lelan
tos\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Jeff\AndroidStudioProjects\LelantosProject\Lelantos\build\libs\Lelantos-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.trapology.lelantos
Error Code:
        -1073741819

        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:69)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:617)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processResources.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:71)
        at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
        ... 59 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.053 sec
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's my build file for good measure. I am noticing there's nothing in the dependencies bracket? is that normal?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

Comment: There's some problem with compiling the resources in your project. Could you do a build and attach the full output from the messages and Gradle Console windows?

Comment: If this helps at all, it all happened after I added a new class in my package.

Comment: Ugh, it's an AAPT crash. We've been seeing some sporadic reports of this. Are you running Windows 8.1, by any chance? We're tracking this in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61308 (though there are some slightly different error codes in that bug report). We don't know the root cause yet so I can't offer a lot of advice on how to fix it. Sorry, I know it's a poor answer.

Comment: No running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Also I am targeting API Level 19. Trying the new HCE api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out I was referencing a string in a XML menu file. I had deleted the string when working on my strings.xml thinking I didn't need it. Added the string backup to the strings.xml file and all is good with the world!

Thanks to Scott Barta for pointing me in the right direction to the aapt crash thread. One of the comments in there lead me to the answer.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much guys, the famous autogenerated and useless "action_settings"